# How to identify a string as filepath and open in file explorer when clicked?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am relatively new to C#/Visual Studio 2015 application development, coming from Android. I am writing a chat application that also allows users to send files to each other. The file transfer functionality is in place; the file gets downloaded to a pre-set folder when received, and the file-path of that file is then shown in the chat box to the recipient. However, that file path is shown as though it were regular text.

How do I make it such that said file-path (and/or urls, ideally) appear as a clickable hyperlinks, that then open said file?

Any help or resources to be pointed to would be most appreciated!

Comment: Which UI framework are you using? WPF, Winforms, another...?

Comment: I believe I'm using Winforms; System.Windows.Forms.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a linkLabel object to show the path, you can add a callback to the event LinkClicked and open a file explorer:

```
    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("C:/");
    }
```

Comment: Currently when a file is received, in the Textbox that holds the chat messages, we .AppendText the received files file path, along with some identifying info of the sender. Do you know of a way to instead of .AppendText, create this link label object you describe? Further, It would seem to me that the callback to the event you outlined below only works for a single instance of a linklabel, given the title linkLabel1_LinkClicked. But I need to be able handle potentially numerous file paths given that multiple files could be sent/received.

Comment: Which type of control are you using to append the text? System.Windows.Forms.TextBox or System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox?

Comment: The object is a TextBox, which I've recently learned is both not ideal for this type of display, and has very little to provide in terms of URL detection + opening on click. I think your original solution of using a linklabel object is most correct, given what I've read in the past few days. It may be easier initially though to transform my TextBoc to a RichTextbox, which does provide URL detection. Taking over others code is strenuous!

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

You should use Uri class to build your url from string:

```
string filePath = "C:\\example.txt";
Uri uri = new Uri(filePath);
return uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: I'm affraid this is not what OP asks.